# Access to sitemap?

Tags: asp.net, sitemap

i created a site map with the name "Web.sitemap" in the root folder, and i need to feed this to google keywords. Any idea how i can access this file? I tried (domain)/Web.sitemap , but it doesn't load.

What is the proper way to access this file?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web.sitemap is typically used by the Sitemap control in ASP.NET to render menus and what not.  It is not exposed publically, and in fact the default IIS configuration will block it from being loaded through the browser.

You may be thinking of a sitemap.xml file, which is an XML description of every page on your site used by search engines and crawlers.  More information on this can be obtained from http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.php

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by feeding it to "Google keywords"? But if you want to submit a sitemap to Google Webmaster Tools (and search engines in general), it is an XML sitemap following the XML sitemaps protocol you want (as Mike wrote)